# hive date dim - customize week number

Tags: hive, hiveql

My requirement is to populate week number against calendar date.The catch is week number will start from October 1 and end at December 7.

So week commencing October 1 will be treated as week 1 , 7th October as week 2 and so on last week number will populate against December 7. Rest will have week number column as NULL. How to do it in hive ?

Comment: "October 1" of a specific year? any year?

Comment: October 7th should still be 1st week. October 8th  should start the 2nd week

Comment: Any year dudu-.-.

Comment: Hive version?...

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as (select date '2014-10-23' as dt)

select  case 
            when dt between cast(concat(date_format(dt,'yyyy'),'-10-01') as date)
                    and     cast(concat(date_format(dt,'yyyy'),'-12-07') as date)

            then datediff (dt,cast(concat(date_format(dt,'yyyy'),'-10-01') as date)) div 7 + 1
        end     as week_number

from    t
```

---

```
+-------------+
| week_number |
+-------------+
|           4 |
+-------------+
```